# register a software as editor in linux

Tags: linux, ubuntu, text-editors, visual-studio-code

I managed to install VSCode on ubuntu 20.04 without root by downloading the zip file. However, when I tried to set it as default editor using

```bsh
update-alternatives --set editor /opt/shared/VSCode-linux-x64/code
```

it reports an error saying that `/opt/shared/VSCode-linux-x64/code` has not been registered so cannot be set. Then I've tried

```bsh
update-alternatives --install /usr/bin/editor editor /opt/shared/VSCode-linux-x64/code 0
```

But again, it reports no permission to create `/var/lib/dpkg/alternatives/editor.dpkg-tmp`.

My question is how to register a binary as editor without root permission.

Answer (score 0):

`update-alternatives` require root permission. Without root privilege, you can set the `EDITOR` variable in your `~/.profile`

```
export EDITOR='/opt/shared/VSCode-linux-x64/code'
```

[Debian Wiki: TextEditor](https://wiki.debian.org/TextEditor#For_users)